Categoryminor(#75100) expected, got "22" which is an instance of String(#2940)
The error identified in the Title is being invoked when running the following
@component = Ccomponent.new(ccomponent_params)
The reponse obtained "22" was isolated with two different submissions:
Parameters: {"authenticity_token"=>"[FILTERED]", "ccomponent"=>{"shop_id"=>"1", "unit_um_id"=>"22", "shelf_life_target"=>"2"}, "commit"=>"submit"}

Parameters: {"authenticity_token"=>"[FILTERED]", "ccomponent"=>{"shop_id"=>"1", "unit_um_id"=>"", "shelf_life_target"=>"2"}, "commit"=>"submit"}

With the second case returning  got "" in the error message.
So the issue is with the relationship for the unit_um_id variable.
The class is defined with two variables that are sourced from the same class.
  belongs_to :um, class_name: 'Categoryminor'
  belongs_to :unit_um_id, class_name: 'Categoryminor', optional: true

The error had not appeared before when the unit_um_id variable did not exist.
Thus it appears rails does not allow two variables to belong to the same class (I can see why: params are always strings and it is the model logic that will convert to an integer: so only one relationship is being processed by that logic here)
um is in lieu of unit of measure and both are needed on the class (consider a bottle whose capacity is 75 cl (1st um), but is purchase in bottles (units - 2nd um).
One could not create the relationship a prior and run an indexed search every time the variable is needed, but that is not very efficient.
How could this model be construed otherwise?

Your issue is here:
belongs_to :unit_um_id, class_name: 'Categoryminor', optional: true

This should be
belongs_to :unit_um, class_name: 'Categoryminor', optional: true

Right now because :unit_um_id is an association it is expecting you to pass an object of that associated type e.g. Categoryminor but you are passing a String.
As a side note um_id is a required parameter because of the belongs_to relationship but it does not appear that you are currently passing one in through ccomponent_params.

Yes, I omitted it for brevity  (it is a longer string of params and was submitted).
